# iOS - In App Purchase stopped working suddenly

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, in-app-purchase

I have developed an application for a customer over a year ago.
This app has In App Purchases, and my customer have been receiving money from her clients that use the app, I can clearly see that in iTunesConnect. Last time someone bought something was in november.

But now all of a sudden, this has stopped working!!! And I don't understand why.
I've checked the Bundle Identifier from XCode which maches the one in AppStore.
Also the product names are equal.

I downloaded the app a couple of minutes ago from AppStore and used the command `idevicesyslog` in order to see all the console output. And the problem is this:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
NSArray *products = response.products;

   if (products.count != 0)
   {
       self.product = products[0];
       NSLog(@"pro: %@", self.product.localizedTitle);
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    } else {
        self.pro1Btn.enabled = YES;
        self.pro2Btn.enabled = YES;
        NSLog(@"pro: not found"); // THIS WAS SHOWN IN CONSOLE OUTPUT
    }
}
```

So the product is never found, but I can clearly see in iTunesConnect that Product ID are the same. They are `pro3` and `pro6`.

Please, help!

EDIT: I can now see the iOS Distribution (Provisioning Profile) has expired!
Can it be that? And how to solve it?

Comment: Check out these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11617871/178805 http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS+distribution+certificate The certificates expire yearly and ideally are renewed before they expiration.

Comment: @JoePasq: Thanks for your comment. But they say the apps wont be broken if the certificate expires. So has it anything to do with my issue? And if I were to create a new iOS Distribution, musn't I upload the app again? I just want it to work without having to upload again, like it did before.

Comment: In app purchases require a valid certificate. Please also see Apple’s [documentation for “Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) and [Adding In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html) to your app. I’m having a hard time finding docs stating exactly how certificates operate with IAP. Definitely renew your certificate and make sure your account is valid.

Comment: @JoePasq: Alright, I will definitely do that. But do I need to re-upload? Seems unfair.

Comment: @JoePasq: I created a new Provisioning Profile and Certificate for Distribituion and they were added in Member Center. Should I expect this to work now? I downloaded the app again, but it does not work.

Comment: I think you will need to distribute a new version signed with your new distribution certificate.

Comment: @JoePasq: Apparently, the contracts in "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" had been expired. So I requested both of them. I guess that should be enough, should take about 2-3 days. I will come back and post an edit if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the contracts in "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" had been expired. So I requested both of them.

Comment: I think the contract is for one year, so you need to update it every year. Not sure though, since I did this for a client and now they manage this by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

have you matched your bundle identifier and povising certifictes are same ?