# iOS in app purchase suddenly not appearing - how long for Connect to update?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

ok so Im having a troubling issue as I need to ship my app soon - all of a sudden the in app purchase dialog does not show up. It was working in past builds.

I believe it is this same problem [iOS - In App Purchase suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989969/ios-in-app-purchase-suddenly-stopped-working) as NONE of my IAP code has been changed.

There was 1 contract that I had to Request in my agreements, taxes, banking section in iTunes connect - I just clicked it and submitted. The IAPs are still not showing however.

How long does it take for Apple to update this? Should I be worried?

Comment: I'm facing same issue. I have uploaded new IPA on testFlight but sudenly disappear after processing.

Comment: If it helps it seems to take about 3 hrs for iTunes to update after you request a contract. Its stupid..